# Running an Excel macro from another workbook

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

I have a subroutine that opens a workbook containing a macro. I then want to run that macro. My code looks like this:

```
Source = "C:\Users\208896\Desktop\Moje Makra\newidea-inbound-query.xlsm"

Workbooks.Open (Source)

Application.Run "newidea-inbound-query.xlsm!InboundQueryMacro"
```

The name of the macro is correct, it is in Module1, all macros are enabled.

I get the error:

> Macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled

Comment: Try to ise the Call-Function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Application.Run ("'Name of the book'!ModuleName.SubName")
```

Comment: Thanks! I only needed to add path of the file and it worked